# Model a finite set of integers

Tags: alloy

Below is an Alloy model representing this set of integers: `{0, 2, 4, 6}`

As you know, the plus symbol `(+)` denotes set union. How can `0` be unioned to `2`? `0` and `2` are not sets. I thought the union operator applies only to sets? Isn't this violating a basic notion of set union?

Second question: Is there a better way to model this, one that is less cognitively jarring?

```
one sig List {
    numbers: set Int
} {
    numbers = 0 + 2 + 4 + 6
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In Alloy, everything you work with is a set of tuples. `none` is the empty set, and many sets are sets of relations (tuples with arity > 1). So also each integer, when you use it, is a set with a relation of arity 1 and cardinality 1. I.e. in Alloy when you use 1 it is really {(1)}, a set of a type containing the atom 1.  I.e. the definition is in reality like:

```
     enum Int {-8,-7,-6,-5,-4,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7}
```

Ints in Alloy are just not very good integers :-( The finite set of atoms is normally not a problem but with Ints there are just too few of them to be really useful. Worse, they quickly overflow and Alloy is not good in handling this at all.

But I do agree it looks ugly. I have an even worse problem with seq.

```
     0-A + 1->B + 2->C + 3->C
```

I already experimented with adding literal seq to Alloy and got an experimental version running. Maybe sets could also be implemented this way:

```
     // does not work in Alloy 4
     seq [ A, B, C, C ] = 0->A + 1->B + 2->C + 3->C 
     set [ 1, 2, 3, 3 ] = 1+2+3
```

Today you could do this:

```
 let x[a , b ] = { a + b }

 run {
    x[1,x[2,x[3,4]]] = 1+2+3+4
 } for 4 int
```

But not sure I like this any better. If macros would have meta fields or would make the arguments available as a sequence (like most interpreters have) then we could do this

```
 // does not work in Alloy 4
 let list[ args ... ] = Int.args // args = seq univ
 run {
    range[ list[1,2,3,4,4] ] = 1+2+3+4
 }
```

If you like the `seq [ A, B, C, C ]` syntax or the varargs then start a thread on the AlloyTools list. As said, I got the `seq [ A, B, C, C ]` working in a prototype.

Comment: Hi @Peter Kriens, thank you for your excellent post! Question: I recall reading that Alloy uses first order logic. I thought "first order logic" means that sets cannot contain sets, i.e., the member of a set cannot be a set. If that is true, how can the Int set contain a {0} set, a {1} set, and so forth? Doesn't that violate the statement that Alloy uses first order logic?

Comment: Well, inside a table an atom is an atom. `Int = { (0), (1), etc.}`. However there is no API to access these atoms. Any operation is always defined on this 'table' (set of tuples). I.e. join, relate, add, etc. The result of all these operations is another table. Therefore, there is no operation that provides you with a single atom, it is always wraps any result in a table. The nice thing about this model is that since the answer can be empty, no null atom is needed.

Comment: @Roger Each integer is an atom. Not a set. What Peter probably meant is that set operators can be used with atoms as well in the sense that a given atom can be seen as a singleton (set containing one element).