# How to constrain a year field to 1-4?

Tags: alloy

There is a set of college students:

```
sig Student {}
```

Each student has an attribute indicating what year he/she is in college (first year, second year, etc.):

```
sig Student {
    year: Int
}
```

The value of year must be 1, 2, 3, or 4.  Here is one way to constrain the year field:

```
sig Student {
    year: Int
} {
 year in {i: Int | i=1 or i=2 or i=3 or i=4}
}
```

Is there a better (simpler, more intuitive) way to constrain year?

Comment: interestingly your already had the answer to this question a year ago ;-): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47739252/model-a-finite-set-of-integers/47739926#47739926

Comment: Ouch! Thanks @Loïc Gammaitoni

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
-- Enumerate
let YEARS = 1+2+3+4

-- or Range
let YEARS = { y : Int | y >= 1 and y <= 4 }

sig Student { year: Int } {
  year in YEARS
}
```

Or more concise

```
sig Student { year: YEARS }
```

Comment: Outstanding! Thank you @Peter Kriens

Comment: I like {year in 1+2+3+4} in a signature fact. You don't really want to introduce a variable every time a field is constrained

Comment: but in this case it is like a type? Isn't the macro (not a variable) more readable? I find that these things also tend to pop up in multiple places which makes a macro easier to maintain? What is the cost of a macro?

Comment: I doubt it is more readable. You want to express that a student can attend different grades, from year 1 to year 4. This knowledge is specific to students. when I focus on the student signature and I see year:YEARS, I don't get this information right away

Comment: I think for a small model like this one it's fine, but add more concepts to the models, and more fields constrained to different intervals of years (e.g. a staff signature containing a "yearsOfExperience" field), and this notation will quickly prove to be less readable, as, at the end of the day, you externalize something which is specific to a signature (imho).

Comment: btw, in my days, YEARS would be called a variable bound by let :-) http://alloytools.org/download/alloy-language-reference.pdf

Comment: Ok, lets agree to differ :-)